# EJB TransactionRolledBackException is not catched

Tags: jpa, exception, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have code like in the snippet below. Question is: Why I can't catch the exception in method1, instead doSomeOtherStuff() is called (which should be prevented in case of an exception)

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class EJBBean1 {

    @EJB
    private EJBBean2 ejb2;

    public void method1(Produkt p){
        try {
            ejb2.method2(p)
            doSomeOtherStuff();//is always called
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            //e is never catched here!!!
        }           
    }
}


@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class EJBBean2 {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "scm")
    protected EntityManager em;


    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void method2(Produkt p) {
        em.merge(p)//Exception rises here (in merge)
    }
}
```

Comment: look at the STACK TRACE of the exception and it tells you where it is thrown from, which tells you where you can catch it

Comment: Any chance you can include the stack trace?  If `doSomeOtherStuff` is getting called, it sounds like the exception isn't getting thrown from `method2`, but when the transaction in `method1` ends.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answer my own question ;-)

Exception does rise in em.merge(), but is not thrown immediately. The JPA container decides when to flush() the merge().

If I change the code a bit:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void method2(Produkt p) {
        em.merge(p)
        em.flush();//Exception rises here
    }
```

I can catch the Exception immediatly.